# Calling a single component multiple times inside another nested component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, recursion

Basically I am working on a page thats purpose is a form for adding a new order to the system. Inside this there is a simple dropdown menu has a list of product names inside which can be added to the order using a component called 'product-autoscroller'.

If the user wanted to add a new product that did not exist in this dropdown list, they would have to go to a separate page that has a component called 'product-management-edit' which is a form for creating a new product and do it there.

Basically I want to be able to add a new product on the create orders page without going to this separate page, and I want to achieve by using a popup dialog menu.

However this 'product-management-edit' which is to exist in the popover has another autoscroller inside which is causing the page to enter an endless loop when accessed, and doesn't give any console errors.

The following is what the code looks like:

```
//Create order component template 

 <label>Create Order</label>
 <product-autoscroller class="ui-form-control" [preSelectProductId]="currentProduct.Id" [addNewRedirect]="true" (onProductSelected)="onProductSelected($event)"></product-autoscroller>

//Product-autoscroller component template

  <p-dialog class="address-book-dialog p-dialog md-dialog" header="New Product" [(visible)]="showCreateProduct" [draggable]="false" [responsive]="true" [resizable]="false">
           <product-management-edit (onNewSelected)="onNewSelected($event)" *ngIf="showCreateProduct"></product-management-edit>
  </p-dialog>


//Product-management edit

 <label>Create Product</label>
 <product-autoscroller class="ui-form-control" [preSelectProductId]="currentProduct.Id" [addNewRedirect]="true" (onProductSelected)="onProductSelected($event)"></product-autoscroller>
```

Basically,

Create order has an autoscroller, which calls create product which also contains an autoscroller which I believe is causing the application to crash.

Is there a way I can achieve this popover menu without causing the application to crash? Perhaps through recursion?

Comment: Is there a fiddle?

Comment: It's a infinite loop, right?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a fiddle for this. Yes it looks like an infinite loop, the browser eventually stops responding.